# Monaco editor: Tokens selected in intellisense popup seem to be prefixed with numbers ("1_", "2_"...)

Tags: monaco-editor

We've have a custom language in place.

When user clicks Ctrl+Space, the intellisense logic provides auto-suggestions. It triggers our logic, and our *getCompletionsAtPosition* returns an array of items, for example:

```
[{
    label: 'foo',
    type: 1
},
{
    label: 'bar',
    type: 1
}]
```

If the user select "bar", what's being "pasted" to the editor is not "bar", but actually "3_bar".

It looks like the prefix "3_" has been added by Monaco.

The prefix doesn't depend on the position of the item in the list - it seems to depend on the role (keyword, operator etc.)

We'd like to understand what causes it and how to remove it.

Thanks!

```
"monaco-editor": "0.21.2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm: it turns out this was my mistake.

As the `monaco.languages.CompletionItem` signature changed, I misspelled the `sortText` so it became `insertText` (for `sortText` we've been prepending these numbers).